# How to find connect relation between (adjacency) labels in image with opencv or other c++ library?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a labeled picture such as below:

---

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 2 2 3
1 0 0 2 3 3
4 5 0 6 0 0
```

---

Now I try to find connect relation (adjacency) in images such as 1 connect to 4, 2 connect to 3 and 6.
0 is the background.
Now I iterate all pixel to record the connection. But I want to know is there a function can do it because my current method work not well in big image.
Thanks for all reply!

Comment: To get a more useful answer, I’d suggest you show your current implementation (but read [mre] first), and  explain exactly why it does work “not well in big image” (is it too slow)?

Answer (score 0):

It is a big question so I'll just share the 2 approaches I know of that you can use to solve this problem. One approach will use Image Processing algorithms and the other approach uses concepts of graph and DSU.

##### Approach 1 (Image Processing based)

First, get the mask image of the current image (labeled picture). This mask image will contain pixel value of 0 if the corresponding pixel is 0 in the current image, or it will contain a pixel value of 255 if the corresponding pixel is greater than 0 in the current image.
Now, in this mask image, find contours using the OpenCV function "findContours" with "RETR_EXTERNAL" flag.
Now if each contour, find all the unique pixel values present in the labeled image.

This will give you sets of numbers that connect to each other.

##### Approach 2 (Graphs and DSU)

Use the property of DSU (Disjoint set union) data structure to obtain the sets of numbers that connect to each other. You can read about DSU from [this video](https://youtu.be/wU6udHRIkcc).

Iterate over each node(pixel) in the labeled image. For each node, check if any neighbor of that node is greater than 0. If found, set the parent of this node to be the neighboring node.
You can increase the speed of this algo by two methods:

1. Ignore the nodes whose parent you have already set using a "is visited" flag array. Also, find only one non-zero neighbor of each node.
2. Use collapsing find method explained at the end of the above video.

Take care of how you define the "neighbor" of a node. You can use 4-connectivity or 8-connectivity according to your problem statement.

Comment: Approach 1 finds all the labels connected to the background, which is not what OP is asking for. Approach 2 finds one neighbor for each label, not all of them, and is likely only useful to identify all the groups of labels that form a connected component. One thing: find neighbors that are larger than 0, but have a different value than the current node.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Approach 2 give me a effient way to speed up algorithm.